# array merge and display with empty data

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, merge

I have two arrays, looks like following

```
$array1 = array("color" => "red","size" => "32");
$array2 = array("color" => "blue","width" => "40");
```

and my php code is as follows

```
    <?php
        $array1 = array("color" => "red","size" => "32");
        $array2 = array("color" => "blue","width" => "40");
        $result = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
        echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

The output of this code is

```
{
color: [
"red",
"blue"
],
size: "32",
width: "40"
}
```

I want to get output like

```
{
color: [
"red",
"blue"
],
size: [
"32",
""
],
width: [
"",
"40"
]
}
```

How I can get this ? Please help me quickly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_merge with an array of default values

```
$array1 = array("color" => "red","size" => "32");
$array2 = array("color" => "blue","width" => "40");
$arrayInit = array("color" => "","width" => "","size"=>"");
$array1 = array_merge($arrayInit,$array1);
$array2 = array_merge($arrayInit,$array2);
$result = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$keys = array_keys(array_merge($array1, $array2)); // get all the keys
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    // set each key in the result array to the value from the input array or a default ''
    $result[$key][] = isset($array1[$key]) ? $array1[$key] : '';
    $result[$key][] = isset($array2[$key]) ? $array2[$key] : '';
}
echo json_encode($result);
```